# Google Data Studio and Slack integration

Tags: google-sheets, slack, google-data-studio, slackbot

How Can I connect my Google Data Studio reports, or parts of them with slack?

I would like that each day appear in slack some report that I will customize in Google Data Studio.

And if I want to do it each time I add a row in a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so not the best way, but you can schedule an emailed data studio report which sends to a slack channel's email address.

You'll need to 'click to expand' and view the PDF in the body of the email. But it works.

Slack channel email addresses:
https://slack.com/slack-tips/send-email-to-slack

Data studio scheduled reports
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9263641?hl=en